# Resharper - Unit Test Runner failed to run tests (System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

I've lost the ability to run or debug tests from Resharper 10 (VS2015, VS2013) test runner.

Resharper - Unit Test Runner failed to run tests (System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException) Found two objects associated with the same URI.

Clean/Rebuild/Restart do not help.

[image]

Comment: I have same issue but the accepted answer not helping me out :(

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Typically I have found that to be a misleading message about an exception that occurred with configuration.  If, for example, you have an app.config or dll specific config file associated with the test project and the config file has an error in it or is unable to be parsed.

Comment: Exactly. I had added a nlog config section to the test runner. However I'd forgotten to add a <configSection><section name="nlog".... Not a very helpful error message!

Comment: Got same problem, quickly solved thanks to your answer :)

Comment: Same here. In my App.config I had a section <appSetting/> in the wrong place. Once that was fixed, everything was alright. Thanks!

Comment: I found a bad log appender for log4net configured.  It was blowing up trying to load the remote file appender.

Comment: I needed to add sections for various technologies being used in our application.  Make sure your App.config is 100%, or you will get this error.

Comment: That was the issue on our end. Thank you.

Comment: removing duplicate connectionStrings section in app.config solved the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. (issue in the app.config of my unit tests project)

the issue in my app.config was that the configSections wasn't the first node in the file.
I've solved it by moving the appSettings node below the configSections node.